# Getting unapproved pull request

Tags: git, branch

I am trying to get this branch - 'branchfor2' from repo1 and have it pushed onto repo2. But the branch in itself is in a pull-request state where it is not yet approved (not yet merged to the main branch in repo1) but the person told me to base it off from there.

Was wondering if it is possible to do so? Get the unapproved pull request branch?
By the way, this is how i did it initially before I realized my contents are different from the pull request
Correct me if I am getting my steps wrong, I am in repo2 directory

- git remote add repo1
- git fetch repo1
- git checkout -b branchfromRepo1 remote/repo1/branchfor2
- git pull
- >>> This is then where I realized the issue is, the contents are different from the pull request

Comment: Git has no knowledge of whether a pull request is approved or not. It's like any other branch. What you're doing seems okay except for the final `git pull`. What's that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @MagnusBäck I did a `git pull` in hopes that it is 'pulling' in the contents from the pull requests that was absent in the branch in itself.. But apparently that didn't work out

Comment: Which pull requests and which branch? Please be explicit. If you create a branch that starts from repo1/branchfor2 you're starting from the current state of that pull request.